# got an error called dense_4 while classifying (CNN)

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I'm currently learning about CNN and trying to classify hand signs( A to Z) for my project this is the error i stumbled upon

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
"dataset\\training_set",
target_size=(64, 64),
batch_size=32,
class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
"dataset/test_set",
target_size=(64, 64),
batch_size=32,
class_mode='categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch=45500,
epochs=8,
validation_data=training_set,
validation_steps=6500)
```

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (26,)

Answer (score 0):

got the answer forgot to add 26 ANN output layers